# How is the value assigned to Dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, cs50, title

This is a very simple problem where it reads file from a CSV with first column header as "title" and then counts how many times the title appears in side the dictionary. But I am not understanding in which step it is assigning the "title" to "titles" dictionary.

The code is:

```
import csv

titles = {}

with open("movies.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        #title is defined here
        title = row["title"].strip().upper()
        if title in titles:
            titles[title] = titles[title] + 1
        else:
            titles[title] = 1
```

If it is assigning inside the else block then why is my second code where I just want to assign values to the dictionary named "titles" and not count the number of times it appears, is not Working?:

```
import csv

titles = {}

with open("movies.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        #title is defined here
        title = row["title"].strip().upper()
        if not title in titles:
            titles[title]
            
print(titles[title])

Error: Key Value error
```

Comment: `titles[title]` gives the value assigned to that title. In the 2nd version you don't do anything with it

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, can you suggest how I can print that in second version without an error?

Comment: Well, you can't. Use the first version. Or *assign something*.

Comment: Dictionary items are key:value pairs which map the key to the value. It has no meaning to just have a dictionary key without a value. So your second version could be `titles[title] =0` or whatever you want. Alternatively you could use a Set or a List to hold just the title(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `titles` is a dictionary `titles[title]` finds the value corresponding to the key `title`. Your second version does not put anything in the dictionary, so `titles[title]` raises a key error.

You say you want to "assign values to the dictionary but not count anything". A dictionary is the wrong structure to use for this. If you want unique titles, you could use a `set`:

```
import csv

titles = set()

with open("movies.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        #title is defined here
        title = row["title"].strip().upper()
        titles.add(title)
            
print(titles)
```

Notice the `add` method only adds something if it does not already exist in the set, rather like a mathematical set. You no longer have key, value pairs, just items.

Answer (score 1):

In your second version, you have this line `titles[title]`, which is not adding the title to your titles dictionary as you do in your first version. Since the title is missing in the dictionary, accessing it will give you a key value error. Why do you have a line `titles[title]` that does nothing?

But I think there's a bigger problem here with your first version of code. You want to add the title to the dictionary when it's not already in it, and add the count by 1 if otherwise. But your first version is doing the opposite, which will throw you an error.